# MDBootstrap Stepper Display Issue

Tags: javascript, html, mdbootstrap

I am new to MDBootstrap and I am trying to get the Stepper Basic example (https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/components/stepper/#docsTabsOverview) working but it is not displaying properly. Maybe I am missing an href in the head element? I am finding it difficult to know which files to include. Would appreciate if someone knows how.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Material Design for Bootstrap</title>
    <!-- MDB icon -->
    <link rel="icon" href="img/mdb-favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <!-- Google Fonts Roboto -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap"
    />
    <!-- MDB -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mdb.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="stepper" data-mdb-stepper-init>
      <li class="stepper-step stepper-active">
        <div class="stepper-head">
          <span class="stepper-head-icon">1</span>
          <span class="stepper-head-text">step1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="stepper-content py-3">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
          incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="stepper-step">
        <div class="stepper-head">
          <span class="stepper-head-icon">2</span>
          <span class="stepper-head-text">step2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="stepper-content py-3">
          Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
          ex ea commodo consequat
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="stepper-step">
        <div class="stepper-head">
          <span class="stepper-head-icon">3</span>
          <span class="stepper-head-text">step3</span>
        </div>
        <div class="stepper-content py-3">
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
          fugiat nulla pariatur
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- MDB -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.umd.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/step.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Showing as:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMHyW.png).

Should look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SNIU.png).

-Thanks

I tried finding where this information is on the MDBootstrap site but was not able to.